# Using three hyphens in md files on github to create a table

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

So I am working with an Rmd file which I later convert into and md file using the `knitr` package. The md file(not mine, just an example) starts with 
[image]

I am interested in how the text between the hyphens at the top is parsed. I want it to look like a table below, 
[image]

but instead when I wrap the text with three hyphens in my repos I get what is highlighted in green

[image]

I have no idea why or what is different in my repo. What I did notice is that if use the three hyphens wrap without using any code chunks in my md file, then I get the desired table. So, somehow the code chunks like that

````
\```css

code chunk

\```
````

mess up the three hyphens wrap being parsed as a table. Any ideas of how to resolve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Better for either [Web Apps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com) (since it has nothing to do with coding) or direct to GitHub:Support

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not that github is parsing `---` as a table delimiter, it is specifically parsing a yaml metadata block located at the top of the file (which uses `---` as it's delimiters) as a table.

See [here](https://github.com/blog/1647-viewing-yaml-metadata-in-your-documents) for the announcement.

Comment: The key is that it is at the very top, i.e. there are no paragraphs breaks.